# Ireport not open after successful installation

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I have successfully installed ireport4.0.2 but whilw open the same i got following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Dimension.<init>(Dimension.java:91)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicProgressBarUI.getPreferredSize(BasicProgressBarUI.java:757)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1615)
    at org.netbeans.modules.progress.ui.NbProgressBar.getPreferredSize(NbProgressBar.java:90)
    at org.netbeans.modules.progress.ui.StatusLineComponent.<init>(StatusLineComponent.java:137)
    at org.netbeans.modules.progress.ui.ProviderImpl.getDefaultWorker(ProviderImpl.java:59)
    at org.netbeans.progress.module.Controller.getProgressUIWorker(Controller.java:128)
    at org.netbeans.progress.module.Controller.getVisualComponent(Controller.java:111)
    at org.netbeans.progress.module.ProgressVisualizerProvider.getStatusLineElement(ProgressVisualizerProvider.java:55)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.MainWindow.getStatusLineElements(MainWindow.java:245)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.MainWindow.decoratePanel(MainWindow.java:219)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.MainWindow.initializeComponents(MainWindow.java:183)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.view.DefaultView.showWindowSystem(DefaultView.java:519)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.view.DefaultView.windowSystemVisibilityChanged(DefaultView.java:498)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.view.DefaultView.changeGUI(DefaultView.java:180)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.ViewRequestor.dispatchRequest(ViewRequestor.java:269)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.ViewRequestor.processVisibilityRequest(ViewRequestor.java:258)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.ViewRequestor.postVisibilityRequest(ViewRequestor.java:195)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.ViewRequestor.scheduleRequest(ViewRequestor.java:117)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.Central.setVisible(Central.java:119)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowManagerImpl.setVisible(WindowManagerImpl.java:776)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowSystemImpl.show(WindowSystemImpl.java:87)
    at org.netbeans.core.NonGui$2.run(NonGui.java:183)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:461)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:104)
[catch] at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:157)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:149)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:110)
SEVERE [global]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Dimension.<init>(Dimension.java:91)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicProgressBarUI.getPreferredSize(BasicProgressBarUI.java:757)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1615)
    at org.netbeans.modules.progress.ui.NbProgressBar.getPreferredSize(NbProgressBar.java:90)
    at org.netbeans.modules.progress.ui.StatusLineComponent.<init>(StatusLineComponent.java:137)
    at org.netbeans.modules.progress.ui.ProviderImpl.getDefaultWorker(ProviderImpl.java:59)
    at org.netbeans.progress.module.Controller.getProgressUIWorker(Controller.java:128)
    at org.netbeans.progress.module.Controller.run(Controller.java:332)
    at org.netbeans.progress.module.Controller.actionPerformed(Controller.java:357)
    at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:271)
    at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:201)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:461)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:104)
[catch] at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:153)
    at java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:515)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:536)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1300)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1253)
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.heartbeat.Installer$1.run(Installer.java:114)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowManagerImpl$Exclusive.run(WindowManagerImpl.java:1335)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:461)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:104)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:157)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:149)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:110)
```

anyone help for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

uninstall the ireport s/w 
then install jdk1.7.. or higher 
& then Reinstall ireport